# System.LimitException: Too many code statements: 200001

Tags: apex, exception

Below is my code.

```
companyList = [
            Select a.Id,a.Name, a.Phone, a.Website, etc... From Account a
            Where a.RecordType.Name = 'Blah'
            ];
String csvString = '';
        for(Account company : companyList)
        {
            csvString += myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Id) + ','
                        + myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Name) + ','
                        + myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Phone) + ','
                        etc...
                        ;

        }
```

How can I solve this error?

I am not doing any insert or update. I am just only select the data and want to do necessary thing.

More..
I use

1.Use SOQL for loop. Still error.

1. I can't put the code in future call. As I want string return back form that method.

3.for limitation the of filters, I already use in SOQL statement by using WHERE.

The way I want to do is below.
1) I will query with Where condition from DB.
2) for each record, I need to parse its data by calling my helper method which will return String.
3) for each return string, I will append to CSVstring.

How can I achieve without hitting limitation.
I know it is really simple to write in Java, Now I am stuck on this simple loop.

Comment: The reason why you're hitting this exception is coz your code is executing more than 20000 statements. If you examine your for loop I see that you're calling the myutil.formatCSVString(string) method lot of times inside the for loop, which in-turn is running the code inside that method causing the 200001 exception. I suggest instead of passing a string to that method, would it be possible to pass the sObject (account) to your method, process the sobject and return the parsed string back the main class?

Comment: hi sameer, I changed like you have said. still error. any idea?

Comment: How many accounts are there in the file you are trying to process ? If this is a very big csv file you may want to break it up into smaller files.

Comment: it is more than 7k.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide the `myUtil.formatCSVString` method body as well?

Comment: Have you looked at the String instance method `escapeCsv`  in lieu of `myUtil.formatCSVString` ? This would avoid the method call and save script statements

Comment: I still the same error on our Winter'14 preview sandbox. Created case with Salesforce for explanation. Will post what I find from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating really big .csv files is a challenge without leveraging the async framework. Try to reduce the calls to that formatCSVString(), or perhaps refactor is such that you only need to call it once per line, rather than one per field.

I second Sdry's point, you may have to break this up into smaller chunks and only process, say, 2000 records at a time. Alternatively, going to the async framework, either through a @future method or a batch job, will get you a limit of 1,000,000 code statements per execution context.

After you construct this .csv string, what are you going to do with it? Can you explain the full use case, end to end, in more detail? What starts off this process and what is the end result?

Comment: I use @future methods and chop into 2 big chunks by requirements.

Comment: Interesting adjustment to this, in Winter '14 they are removing the script statement limit! It's being replaced by a limit on the overall time a process can execute. Perhaps your code will run just fine on a Winter '14 build.

Comment: Curiously, I'm still seeing script limits on the Winter 14 preview orgs and Winter 14 sandboxes. I wonder if they just haven't switched over yet, or are perhaps thinking of changing their mind?

Comment: There is a great article on processing large CSV files using Batch Apex here, http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your string concatentions with `String.join` which might help a little.

```
String[] csv = new String[] {};

for(Account company : companyList) {
    String[] csvRow = new String[] {
        myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Id),
        myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Name),
        myUtil.formatCSVString(company.Phone)
    };

    csv.add(String.join(csvRow, ','));
}

String csvString = String.join(csv, '');
```